# Laravel's $request->user()->id; is giving me first logged in user not current one

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

Am developing in laravel 10, i use sanctum token authentications
but on my controller methods only returns first logged in user not current one

```
public function getUser( Request $request ) {

 return $request->user()->id;//is giving me previous logged in user id not current one

}
```

until i re-start the local server and logged in then i get the current user id, if i log out and login as different person again i get previous logged person not current one

Comment: Have you tried getting the user through the `Auth` facade instead? `Auth::user()->id` or `Auth::id()`.

Comment: Thanks @IGP. this works for me, i thing you should post it as answer so we can vote it up

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the user through the `Auth` facade instead.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::user()->id
// or
Auth::id()
```